# Electrical switch/relay that will stay on once triggered (regardless of future inputs)

Tags: relay, latch, scr

I am looking for an electrical device that will allow for me to take an input (that will change from high to low to high again) and have it trigger an output (turn high when my input is low) but stay at this high state regardless of any future inputs.

Does something like this exist? Sorry if this is a duplicate, I just don't know what terminology to search with.

Thank you in advance,

Julia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is simple latching behavior.  There are lots of ways to get that.

You can wire up a relay so that it keeps itself energized once it is energized.  A SCR is a electonic device that inherently latches once triggered, and stays on as long as some minimum current is supplied.  There are various ways of wiring up transistors to do this.  Basically anything with a gain greater than 1 can be arranged to latch.  There are digital gates specifically for this purpose, and of course a microcontroller can be trivially programmed for this function.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to buy magnetically latching relays, if you don't want to do this electronically. If you're OK with an electronic latch, an SCR (Silicon-Controlled Rectifier) circuit would do the job. Or maybe a set-reset latch (SR flip-flop) would do it, if you don't need to drive a relay.

Answer (score 3):

Things like that do exist, and they're called, generically, "latches".

There are a huge number of hits [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=latch%20circuit&espv=2&biw=1137&bih=783&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ic9bVI7xG4W6ogSQ9oLQDA&ved=0CDcQ7Ak&dpr=0.9), which should get you started, and if you want to go the mechanical route, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=latching%20relay&espv=2&biw=1137&bih=783&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=49BbVK2EEZOAygTaooLwBA&ved=0CE4Q7Ak&dpr=0.9) are a bunch of latching relay circuits.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a latching relay is to use one of the contacts of the relay to hold it energized, like this:

[image]

Pressing the NO (normally open) pushbutton S1 operates the DPST (double-pole, single-throw) relay K1, and contact P1/S1 keeps it operated, even after the pushbutton is released.  Pressing the NC (normally closed) pushbutton S2 release the relay.  The second contact P2/S2 is used to control whatever circuit is needed.

One could of course also use a DPDT (double-pole, double-throw relay as well.